# Best Wireless Access Point for HOT environment

Tags: wifi, networking, access-point

I'm looking to extend wifi into a detached garage 200ft away from my house.  The metal shed is not insulated or climate-controlled, and can get quite HOT during the Florida summers.

Can anyone recommend a specific Wireless AP capable of operating in these extreme temperatures? Should I look at specialized outdoor hardware, or buy the cheapest AP I can find, and plan on replacing it often?

Comment: What kind of budget do you have? Are you going to run Ethernet between your garage and house?

Comment: Do you have the ability to plug in a nearby low-power fan to blow on it? Serious question.

Comment: Could you mount a wifi router outside the garage directly under the eaves?

Comment: Small budget, I can buy a new AP, but lets just say I'm not buying Cisco.  It will be fed by ethernet.  A fan would be an option if there's not a line of heat-tolerant equipment.

Comment: In any case, I would keep it as low to the ground as possible without putting it at risk for flooding. The higher in your shed it goes, the hotter it will be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the [EnGenius ENS202 N300](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833168115) on Newegg.

This is a brand of wireless equipment this is designed for outdoor use. It rated up to 158 degrees. It's also water resistant with an IP55 rating, meanint its resistant to dust and low pressure water from all angles.

If this model doesn't cut it for you, this company makes a wide range of outdoor rated networking tools.

Also, another note. That tin wall is going to radiate heat like an oven. I would consider mounting a wooden block between the wall and the AP to act as a heat sink, it will absorb the heat from the metal wall, and reduce the risk of hitting the 158 degree threshold. *edit* I mention this because my minds eye had the access point on the outside wall of the garage, odd assumption to make...